# HTTP Headers: Document Policy vs. Permissions-Policy/Feature-Policy

Tags: http, header

I'm checking the options to harden my web app by setting the appropriate HTTP headers.

Besides the [`Content Security Policy (CSP)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)  there are two another approaches: [`Document Policy`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-permissions-policy/document-policy.html#relation-to-feature-policy) and [`Permissions-Policy (Feature-Policy)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy).

I've checked the W3C [Relation to Feature Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-permissions-policy/document-policy.html#relation-to-feature-policy) documentation, but still can't grasp the clear answer wherever I need to set both policies: Document and Permissions or it is overshooting and it's enough to set just Permissions-Policy?

P.S. Feel free to forward this question to the SE's [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) portals, if the question doesn't fit so much this portal.

Answer (score 0):

Document-Poicy is for more performance/best-practice options. Permissions-Policy is for handling "powerful" features that you don't want third-parties or new devs using.